# pthread_mutex_trylock and pthread_mutex_unlock cause segmentation fault

Tags: c, pthreads

A mutex is required to be unlocked once the thread is canceled, in order to avoid deadlock. So I devised the following method:

```
// file_a.c
pthread_attr_t attr;
...
rc2 = pthread_attr_init(&attr);
ERR_IF( rc2 != 0 );
rc2 = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
ERR_IF( rc2 != 0 );
rc2 = pthread_create(&destroy_thread, &attr, destroy_expired_sessions, NULL);
ERR_IF( rc2 != 0 );
...
pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

static void *destroy_expired_sessions(void *t)
{
    ...
    (void)t;

    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup_handler, NULL);
    while (1)
    {
            ... // doing some work here

            sleep(min_timeout);
    }
    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);
}

static void cleanup_handler(void *arg)
{
    (void)arg;

    authSessionListMutexUnlock();
}

// file_b.c
typedef struct
{
    /** Mutex for using this structure. */
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    /** The list of Session nodes. */
    cList *list;
} SessionList;

SessionList *globalSessionList = NULL;

...

void authSessionListMutexUnlock()
{
    if (pthread_mutex_trylock(&globalSessionList->mutex) == EBUSY)
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&globalSessionList->mutex);
}
```

The reason I use pthread_mutex_trylock() here is to avoid a second pthread_mutex_unlock() if the mutex has been unlocked somewhere else.

However, the  pthread_mutex_trylock() and pthread_mutex_lock() here caused a segmentation fault.

But, the program here seems innocuous, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to [initialize your mutex using `pthread_mutex_init()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_mutex_init.html).

From experience, using an un-initialized mutex is a fairly safe bet to crash your program.

Another option is if you're attempting to unlock the mutex from another thread than you locked it from. The behavior of that operation is undefined.

Edit: A quick remark on the trylock/unlock; if the mutex is locked, you'll get `EBUSY` and unlock it, if the mutex is free, trylock will succeed in locking it and it won't be unlocked. In other words, it will toggle the lock/unlock status of the mutex. Is that really as you intended?

Comment: I forgot to list the initialization code, but the mutex does get initialized with `pthread_mutex_init(&(globalSessionList->mutex), &mutexAttr)` in the beginning, before the mutex is used.

Comment: By the way, the log shows the segmentation fault happened with `pthread_mutex_trylock()`, before `pthread_mutex_unlock()` gets a chance to run.

Comment: @QiangXu As far as I can tell, the only way trylock() can crash is if there's something wrong with the actual mutex, either initialization or some kind of memory corruption. If it was unlock() failing, there's the possibility that the mutex was locked in another thread and it fails because lock in one thread, unlock in another results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Hmmm, your comment on the toggling of the lock status is helpful. I need to consider the scenario more carefully.

Comment: Oops, you are right, Joachim. More detailed log does show that there is a memory violation - The `cleanup_handler()` function gets run only after `authDeinit()`, in which the global mutex struture is freed. That's why a further `pthread_mutex_trylock()` caused a segmentation fault. But here is another question: `pthread_cancel()` is called before `authDeinit()`. How come the cleanup handler runs after it?